# Android Navigation Component: Go back to previous screen without loose of state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Hi there I am developing an Android app with the new Navigation components library.
I've come across the following issue:

Let's say we have two screens, [A] and [B]. 
Screen [A] contains static and dynamic views. The static ones are defined in the xml layout file and the dynamic ones are generated at runtime based upon some web requests.

Now I tick some static and dynamic checkboxes and navigate to Screen [B] with `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.goFromAtoB)`. After some time the user returns to screen [A] with `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack();`.

However, only the **static views/checkboxes** retained their state in Screen [A] meaning that they are still ticked.
The dynamic checkboxes are needlessly generated again and therefore loose their states. Is there any elegant way to tell the Fragment/Screen A to not ditch all the view states but rather retain them even after the user exits said screen?

Comment: you can use [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) as current navigation APIs doesn't support saving fragment state

Comment: man that's just disappointing. But it's strange that the state of the static views is saved isn't it?